# angularjs default text for empty ng-repeat on javascript object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem getting default text to print out for an empty ng-repeat that is iterating over a javascript object.  Normally I would just do a `<div ng-show="object.length==0">EMPTY SET</div>"` but you can't call length on a javascript object.  I have a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/C4t4LystX/zHJv8/8/.  Basically I just need to know when the ng-repeat has no objects to repeat over so I can show some default text. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct, there is no object.length in javascript.  Because you are resetting sources to an empty object, you need to check to see if the object is empty, or has some sources.  You can write a simple function called isEmpty.

```
   <div ng-show="isEmpty(sources)">
          EMPTY SOURCES
   </div>

function Ctrl1($scope) {
    $scope.sources = {source1:{id:"source1"},source2:{id:"source2"}};

    $scope.cleanSources = function(){
        $scope.sources = {};                               
    };

    $scope.isEmpty = function (obj) {
       return angular.equals({},obj); 
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zHJv8/21/

**EDIT**: Changed isEmpty to use angular.equals instead of for each loop.

Comment: Not sure but you could probably write the isEmpty function like: return angular.equals({}, obj); turning it into 1-liner.

Comment: Does anyone know why this doesn't work -- i.e., trying to inline the call to angular.equals()?: <div ng-show="angular.equals({},sources)">EMPTY</div>

Comment: Thanks, I've added the isEmpty function to my scope.  I was hoping there would be a good solution that could be done straight on the html, but at least this is concise and generic.

Comment: @MarkRajcok You are only allowed basic expressions, and functions that are defined within the current scope.  The angular namespace is outside of the scope.

Answer (score 1):

ng-show works from a boolean expression, so all you need is to set something to true when the set is empty, and to false when it has something in it. Here's a fiddle with one way to do it:

Here's the idea:

```
$scope.cleanSources = function(){
        $scope.sources = {}; 
        $scope.empty = true;    
    };
```

And here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/J38r2/

This method doesn't directly test whether sources is empty. To do that you could:

http://jsfiddle.net/timothybone/HXgbR/4/

And of course the docs show the same idea:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow

Comment: Of course, you will need to remember to set $scope.empty to false any time sources is repopulated for any reason.