# AngularJS display message when object is empty in repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and the repeater to iterate through some results.  There's also a filter applied for searching.

There's two conditions that I would want to be able to handle and am looking for the most "angular" way.

The first condition is if there are no results to begin with.

The second condition is if when using the filter, there are no results returned.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845409/angularjs-default-text-for-empty-ng-repeat-on-javascript-object), which seems like it would be adequate and I could create one for each condition.  However, is there anyway with native angular directives to handle these conditions, without requiring code in the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add ngSwitch directive on filtered array and display different HTML depending on it's length.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGPew/1/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<div ng-init="filtered = (friends | filter:searchText)">
    <div>{{(friends | filter:searchText).length}}</div>
    <div ng-switch="(friends | filter:searchText).length">
        <span ng-switch-when="0">Nothing was found</span>
        <table id="searchTextResults" ng-switch-default>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="friend in filtered | filter:searchText">
                <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
                <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
$scope.searchText = "";
$scope.friends = [{
    name: 'John',
    phone: '555-1276'
}, {
    name: 'Mary',
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'
}, {
    name: 'Mike',
    phone: '555-4321'
}, {
    name: 'Adam',
    phone: '555-5678'
}, {
    name: 'Julie',
    phone: '555-8765'
}];
}
```

Another option is to apply $filter("filter") on friends array directly in controller, which will shorten HTML markup.

Comment: I did notice that sometimes the "Nothing was found" message will flicker quickly when refreshing/loading.  I've added an ng-cloak to it, but doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You can try switching CSS classes instead of DOM nodes. Make "Nothing was found" hidden by default and show it according to an array length.

Answer (score 7):

You Can Use This Syntax For Showing Message When No Data Found

```
<p ng-show="(friends | filter:searchText).length==0">Sorry No Result Found</p>`
```

Where friends is the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) allows you to give an alias to the resulting items after all filters have been processed.
You can then use this alias to display your message.

```
<p ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText as displayedFriends">
    {{friend.name}}
</p>
<p ng-if="!displayedFriends.length">
    Nothing was found
</p>
```