# Unable to display "Not found" using ng-hide and filters in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, search

I am trying to implement instant search using filters in angular js. I want the "Not Found!!" message to be displayed when the filter is empty i.e. when no matching result is found. The `ng-hide` directive doesn't seem to work when filter array is empty.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="places as p">
  <div>

    <input type="text" ng-model="cname" />
    <div ng-repeat="country in abc=(p.countries|filter:cname)">
      <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>{{abc.length}}
      <span ng-hide="abc.length">Not Found!!</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var arr = [{

      name: 'germany'
    }, {

      name: 'mexico'
    }, {

      name: 'india'
    }, {

      name: 'UK'
    }, {

      name: 'argentina'
    }];


    app.controller('places', function() {

      this.countries = arr;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS display message when object is empty in repeater](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994666/angularjs-display-message-when-object-is-empty-in-repeater)

Comment: Try moving the ng-hide outside ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank You. Moving the ng-hide outside ng-repeat worked!! . :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `ng-hide` outside `ng-repeat` worked!!

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="cname" />
<div ng-repeat="country in abc=(p.countries|filter:cname)">
  <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>{{abc.length}}
</div>
<span ng-hide="abc.length">Not Found!!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code like below:

```
    <div ng-repeat="country in abc = (p.countries | filter:cname)">
      <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>{{abc.length}}
      <span ng-show="abc.length < 1">Not Found!!</span>
    </div>
```

**UPDATED:** **ng-hide** changed to **ng-show**

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-controller="places as p">
  <div>

    <input type="text" ng-model="cname" />
    <div ng-repeat="country in abc=(p.countries|filter:cname)">
      <h1>{{country.name}}</h1>{{abc.length}}
      
    </div>
    <span ng-hide="abc.length">Not Found!!</span>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    var arr = [{

      name: 'germany'
    }, {

      name: 'mexico'
    }, {

      name: 'india'
    }, {

      name: 'UK'
    }, {

      name: 'argentina'
    }];


    app.controller('places', function() {

      this.countries = arr;
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have added ng-hide inside the loop thats why it's not display.